# Disallow Export * from ""

Tags: reactjs, webpack, export, babeljs

So I have a React app and I want to disable re-exporting all the exports.

Here is an example which should give me an error and the build should fail.

```
one.js

import path from 'path'

export default function A() {
  return <main />
}


export function getStaticProps() {
  path;
  return { props: { } };
}
```

```
two.js

export * from './one'
```

Comment: are you using a linter? You could look at the rules around usage of this and then use the lint as a prereq on a build so the build would fail

Comment: @JohnRuddell I am using eslint and I have .eslintrc.json file as well

Comment: I think you'd want something like this. https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-imports if you look at the examples

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I'd really like to be able to do this myself

Comment: @JohnRuddell that rule doesn't cover this particular use case

Comment: @BenWainwright Sorry I meant to link [`no-restricted-exports`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-exports). Although I don't know if it'll fully suffice the ask, its more manual in individual modules, where you can define what its export restrictions are.

Comment: @JohnRuddell as I said, it doesn't cover this particular problem